# React native Nodejs compatibility issue

Tags: node.js, react-native, compatibility

I'm new to react native. I'm facing problems Node js version compatibility issue. I have installed the Node 14 version in my system and he gave me an error when I created a new project in react native "You are currently running Node v14.21.3 but React Native requires >=16."
but when I upgrade my node version to the latest version. my other project gave me the node js version compatibility issue(Angular).
how I overcame this problem. Thanks

I have tried different methods to overcome this issue like upgrading and downgrading the version of the node. If the react native project works fine with the latest nodejs version, the Angular project gives an error.

Comment: What's your OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general answer would be to use `nvm`

Here's the link to the github repo: [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

That way you can always switch between node versions with

```
$ nvm use 16
Now using node v16.9.1 (npm v7.21.1)
$ node -v
v16.9.1
$ nvm use 14
Now using node v14.18.0 (npm v6.14.15)
$ node -v
v14.18.0
$ nvm install 12
Now using node v12.22.6 (npm v6.14.5)
$ node -v
v12.22.6
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yes, this works for me.
first, I uninstalled nodejs from the system and installed NVM and I installed different versions of nodejs using NVM and easily switched between them. Special thanks for your timely response.

Comment: Thanks for the approved answer! Glad I could help!